# Can't use &lt; correctly in my code

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I get this code from an android book, but I have the following error: Validate resource references inside android xml files.
I also noticed that the tag immediately after "String" never opens, so the book wants create the tag "<" with the escape symbol.

```
  <data class="ArrayTest">
    <import type="android.util.SparseArray"/>
    <import type="java.util.Map"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable name="list" type="List&lt;String>"/>
    <variable name="sparse" type="SparseArray&lt;String>"/>
    <variable name="map" type="Map&lt;String, String>"/>
    <variable name="index" type="int"/>
    <variable name="key" type="String"/>
</data>
```

Full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data class="ArrayTest">
    <import type="android.util.SparseArray"/>
    <import type="java.util.Map"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable name="list" type="List&lt;String>"/>
    <variable name="sparse" type="SparseArray&lt;String>"/>
    <variable name="map" type="Map&lt;String, String>"/>
    <variable name="index" type="int"/>
    <variable name="key" type="String"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{list[index]}"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{sparse[index]}"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{map[key]}"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text='@{@string/param_example("Pippo", 50)}'
        />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Java code:

```
ArrayTest mapTestBinding = DataBindingUtil
        .setContentView(this, R.layout.array_test);
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
SparseArray<String> sparse = new SparseArray<>();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
mapTestBinding.setList(list);
mapTestBinding.setSparse(sparse);
mapTestBinding.setMap(map);
mapTestBinding.setKey("key");
mapTestBinding.setIndex(10);
String value = getResources().getString(R.string.param_example, "Pippo", 20);
```

Error:

http://pastebin.com/3CZmTLzM

Comment: please provide your full code

Comment: are you sure you have to add the `data` to your **layout** file? it should be somewhere in `values`

Comment: Can you also add the java class ArrayTest and **the error message**

Comment: I post the java code, ArrayTest is a class created in run time

Comment: I added the error on pastebin link

Comment: I will look after that tomorrow

Comment: Tips for posting here: we do not use [solved] title hacks, preferring instead to keep titles in a good condition, and use the purpose-made tick feature adjacent to all questions. If you answer is substantively different to the others, and yours is the best solution, then feel free to self-accept it, by clicking the tick mark until it turns green. Secondly, if a high-rep user edits your post, consider the likelihood that they know the editing and presentation conventions here rather well, and if you are minded to roll back, please ping them first. Thanks.

Comment: Thirdly, where you believe other answers were helpful, consider upvoting them, to encourage them to help others again in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show it in your code, but do make sure the schema is at the top of the xml file.

Your xml should look like:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data class="ArrayTest">
    <import type="android.util.SparseArray"/>
    <import type="java.util.Map"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable name="list" type="List&lt;String>"/>
    <variable name="sparse" type="SparseArray&lt;String>"/>
    <variable name="map" type="Map&lt;String, String>"/>
    <variable name="index" type="int"/>
    <variable name="key" type="String"/>
</data>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved using "Inspection android resources validation options" and then "Run inspection on" as shown below:

[Inspection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f0wI.png)

this has allowed me to modify the code in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data class="ArrayTest">
    <import type="android.util.SparseArray"/>
    <import type="java.util.Map"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable name="list" type="List&lt;String>"/>
    <variable name="sparse" type="SparseArray&lt;String>"/>
    <variable name="map" type="Map&lt;String, String>"/>
    <variable name="index" type="int"/>
    <variable name="key" type="String"/>
</data>
```

Anyway thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

try encoding the xml file with utf-8.

Comment: I did it with

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: then you should try to replace &lt; by the actual character (<)

Answer (score 0):

`&lt;` is the `HTML` special entity for the `lower than` sign: `<`
Maybe there were some mistakes made at the printing of the book.

Try this:

```
<data class="ArrayTest">
    <import type="android.util.SparseArray"/>
    <import type="java.util.Map"/>
    <import type="java.util.List"/>
    <variable name="list" type="List<String>"/>
    <variable name="sparse" type="SparseArray<String>"/>
    <variable name="map" type="Map<String, String>"/>
    <variable name="index" type="int"/>
    <variable name="key" type="String"/>
</data>
```

This should work because the `diamond` operator is complete now.

**EDIT**

If you want to use `<` and `>` in your xml file use `&lt;` for `<`, `&gt;` for `>` (and `&amp;` for `&` if you need it)

Comment: I don't think so cause this chapter is explaining how to use the escape symbol...

Comment: @J.proto so you want to have the type `List<String>` ? This is very uncommon. you could use: `List&lt;String&gt;` which results in lower and greater than

Comment: yes, that's the target, but nothing to do either with 
  <variable name="list" type="List&lt;String&gt;"/>

Comment: @J.proto i need your full code (java included) and **the *full* error message**

Answer (score 0):

```
<data>
<import type="android.util.SparseArray"/>
<import type="java.util.Map"/>
<import type="java.util.List"/>
<variable name="list" type="List&lt;String&gt;"/>
<variable name="sparse" type="SparseArray&lt;String&gt;"/>
<variable name="map" type="Map&lt;String, String&gt;"/>
<variable name="index" type="int"/>
<variable name="key" type="String"/>
```

I also have meet the same proplem as yours. you can declared like this in you xxx.xml file. Though the xxx.xml file may present an error, your apk can build successfully and run .   I am not good at English, sorry.